# Filepicker.io + s3 bucket using ios sdk

Tags: ios, filepicker.io

I have a filepicker.io account which is set up to use my s3 bucket for storage.
I can upload a file from iOS but no one can view it.

And I can't find a way to set access:public, because ios sdk doesn't allow to customize store request.

What are default access settings when using ios sdk to upload a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ink Filepicker iOS library doesn't support setting s3 access levels. As a workaround, you should use the filepicker url that returns, as it is public.